# Error only on server with PDO: "Only variables can be passed by reference"/"Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference pdo"

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting the following errors when trying to loop through an array on my server to bind statements with PDO:

"Only variables can be passed by reference"
or
"Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference pdo"

Works fine on my local XAMPP.

Code:

```
$sql = rest of sql query etc.

$loop = 1;
foreach ($animal_array $ani)
{
    if ($loop == 1) {$sql .= " WHERE animal.id= :animal_id".$loop; }
    else            {$sql .= " OR animal.id= :animal_id".$loop;}
    $loop++;
}   

$stmt = $crud->db->prepare($sql);

$loop = 1;
foreach ($animal_array as $ani)
{   
    $stmt->bindParam(':animal_id'.$loop, $ani['animal_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $loop++;
}
```

Also tried this at the end as I read somewhere that concatonations sometimes aren't liked:

```
foreach ($animal_array as $ani)
{   
    $ref = ":animal_id".$loop;
    $stmt->bindParam($ref, $ani['animal_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $loop++;
}
```

.

**EDIT:**
The array contains other values, sort of like this:

```
$animal_array['animal_id'];
$animal_array['name'];
$animal_array['colour'];
$animal_array['quantity']; etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to use [`bindValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) for pure input parameters. The [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) method is reserved for binding variables which can be used as input *but also* return query results (output).

Though that doesn't explain your issue. But we don't know what your array contains.
It's not the key generation / concatenation for sure.

Comment: The array contains lots of other info but animal_id is a number. I've edited that information in to my orignal question.

Comment: I tried bindValue and it didn't work but now it does... not sure where I went wrong before, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you're overcomplicating matters... why not just pass the array to [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) directly:

```
$sql .= 'WHERE animal.id IN ('
     .     '?'.str_repeat(',?', count($animal_array['animal_id'])-1)
     .  ')';

$qry = $crud->db->prepare($sql);
$qry->execute($animal_array['animal_id']);
```

Comment: I didn't know about "str_repeat". That will be really useful, thank you. However I don't think my array will work like that in this instance though.

Comment: @penpen: Why not?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's a multidimensional array

Comment: @penpen: Apologies, I hadn't seen that update to your question; I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm normally pretty good with arrays so I don't know why it had never occurred to me to use on in that way in $qry->execute... Thank you for all your help!